Reusing objects in C#.NET in a similar way as done in VBScript
I have a dynamic solution created with VBScript that terminates objects before reusing them. My users typically have two or more IBM Personal Communications (PCOMM) sessions open on their Desktop to do their daily tasks. Some of those sessions are logged into business proprietary applications and need to be left alone. They also can't use their "A" session as that's their production session. To handle this, I've developed this logic:
Set Connect_Manager = CreateObject("pcomm.autECLConnMgr")
Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
Set ObjEmulator = CreateObject("pcomm.auteclsession")

autECLConnList.Refresh
Num = autECLConnList.Count
PrevNum = Num

If Num = 0 Then
   MsgBox "You must have at least two PCOMM sessions open to use this tool." & vbnewline & vbnewline &  "Program is now terminating.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "No Session Error"
   SetEverythingToNothing
   WScript.Echo "EXIT"
   WScript.Quit
End If

strSession = autECLConnList(Num).Name
Connect_Manager.autECLConnList.Refresh

ObjEmulator.SetConnectionByName (strSession)
Window_Title = ObjEmulator.autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle

If InStr(Window_Title, "HOSTORS") <> 0 Or strSession = "A" Or InStr(Window_Title, "NDB") <> 0 Then
   Set ObjEmulator = Nothing
   Loop_Count = 1
   Do
      ResEmulator = "No"
      PrevNum = PrevNum - 1
      If PrevNum = 0 Then
         MsgBox "You need to have more than one session open." & vbnewline & "Program is now terminating.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "One Session Error"
         SetEverythingToNothing
         WScript.Echo "EXIT"
         WScript.Quit
      Else
         strSession = autECLConnList(PrevNum).Name
         If strSession = "A" Then
            MsgBox "You cannot use your production (A) session." & vbnewline & "Please open another session." & vbnewline & "Program is now terminating.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Production Session Error"
            SetEverythingToNothing
            WScript.Echo "EXIT"
            WScript.Quit
            Exit Do
         Else
            Set ObjEmulator = CreateObject("pcomm.auteclsession")
            Connect_Manager.autECLConnList.Refresh
            ObjEmulator.SetConnectionByName (strSession)
            Window_Title = ObjEmulator.autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle
            If InStr(Window_Title, "NDB") <> 0 Or InStr(Window_Title, "HOSTORS") <> 0 Then
               Set ObjEmulator = Nothing
            Else
               ResEmulator = "Yes"
            End If
         End If
      End If
      Loop_Count = Loop_Count + 1
      If Loop_Count = 10 Then
         MsgBox "Unable to connect to a session." & vbnewline & "Please make sure you have working sessions." & vbnewline & "Program is now terminating.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Production Session Error"
         SetEverythingToNothing
         WScript.Echo "EXIT"
         WScript.Quit
         Exit Do
      End If
   Loop Until ResEmulator = "Yes"
End If

My department is moving away from VBScript and towards C#.NET. I've created a VERY similar version of the VBScript code.
UPDATED
AutConnList autECLConnList = new AutConnList();
AutConnMgr Connect_Manager = new AutConnMgr();
AutSess ObjEmulator = new AutSess();
       
autECLConnList.Refresh();
int Num = autECLConnList.Count;
int PrevNum = Num;

if (Num == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must have at least two PCOMM sessions open to use this tool." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Program is now terminating.", "No Session Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
    MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
    return;
}

string strSession = autECLConnList[Num].Name;
autECLConnList.Refresh();

ObjEmulator.SetConnectionByName(strSession);
string Window_Title = ObjEmulator.autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle;


if (Window_Title.IndexOf("HOSTORS") == 0 || strSession == "A" || Window_Title.IndexOf("NDB") == 0)
{
    ObjEmulator = null;
    int Loop_Count = 1;
    string ResEmulator = "No";
    do
    {
        PrevNum -= 1;
        if (PrevNum == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to have more than one session open." + Environment.NewLine + "Program is now terminating.", "One Session Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            strSession = autECLConnList[PrevNum].Name;
            if (strSession == "A")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot use your production (A) session." + Environment.NewLine + "Please open another session." + Environment.NewLine + "Program is now terminating.", "Production Session Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                ObjEmulator = new AutSess();
                autECLConnList.Refresh();
                ObjEmulator.SetConnectionByName(strSession);
                Window_Title = ObjEmulator.autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle;
                if (Window_Title.IndexOf("HOSTORS") == 0 || Window_Title.IndexOf("NDB") == 0)
                {
                    ObjEmulator = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    ResEmulator = "Yes";
                }
            }
        } 
        Loop_Count++;
        if (Loop_Count == 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to a session." + Environment.NewLine + "Please make sure you have working sessions." + Environment.NewLine + "Program is now terminating.", "Production Session Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
            return;
        }
    } while (ResEmulator == "Yes");
}

My issue is I'm getting the CS0136 - A local or parameter named 'ObjEmulator' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter when I'm trying to redeclare AutSess ObjEmulator = new AutSess();. I'm looking for a similar way to keep this dynamic like the VBScript code. Since ObjEmulator = null; doesn't fully kill the object in C#.NET like Set ObjEmulator = Nothing does in VBScript, does anyone have advice on how this can be done?

You could just rename the inner variable ... AutSess ObjEmulatorLocalScope = new AutSess(); Or I think you could just not redeclare the variable: ObjectEmulator = new AutSess() as whatever the error message says I think that's the issue. For that matter, not really seeing why you create the AutSess object at the top of your script as I don't see how its being used until you get inside the loop anyway.

Also as food for thought, possibly you don't need to destroy the old one and create a new one - maybe just change its connection and use the same instance (if that's possible).

@topsail The object is used to connect to the first session found, ObjEmulator.SetConnectionByName(strSession);, and get its window title, string Window_Title = ObjEmulator.autECLWinMetrics.WindowTitle;, immediately before the if statement that goes into the loop. In the VBScript, this is where ObjEmulator is set to Nothing so it can be reused in the loop. I'm looking to do the same thing, if possible, in C#. Can you please expand more on your idea of changing the connection?

I don't know enough about your emulator object to say for sure, but if you simply change its connection does it work as needed (i.e., the same as it does if you create a new one and give it a new connection)? You do not need to explicit objects to nothing in Csharp, you can just your reference variable to a new object instance (ObjectEmulator = new AutSess()). The object will be disposed of ("garbage collected", "set to nothing") eventually. If you do want to explicit set a variable to nothing in C# that would be by calling its dispose method (ObjEmulator.Dispose())

@topsail That worked!! I've updated the code to show the current C#.NET code the does the exact same thing as the VBScript code. Thanks for the advice!
